# ASP.MVC Settings Object Model Binding

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to store a **settings object** with every user (dont want a settings table) but I think I am on a competely wrong way. Thats the way I tried to get it done:

```
// this is the user model
public class AppUser: IdentityUser
{
  public string FirstName {get; set;}
  public string LastName {get; set;}
  public UserSettings Settings {get; set;} // the desired object
}

// the settings class
[DataContract]
public class UserSettings
{
   [DataMember]
   public bool ANiceProperty {get; set;}
   [DataMember]
   public enum AnotherNiceEnumPropery {get; set;}
   [DataMember]
   public UserSettingsSubClass SubClass {get; set;}
   // and so on...
}

// another sub-settings class
[DataContract]    
public class UserSettingsSubClass
{
   [DataMember]
   public bool ANiceProperty {get; set;}
}
```

What is the best way to work with it, e.g. User.Settings.Property? In my crazy PHP and MySQL times I hat to create an array - serialize it - stored as string - deserialized it - back to array. But I think there is a better way, isnt it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyway, you have to serialize the settings to string. I suggest you to use [Json.Net library](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html)

Example of usage:

```
Product product = new Product();

product.Name = "Apple";
product.ExpiryDate = new DateTime(2008, 12, 28);
product.Price = 3.99M;
product.Sizes = new string[] { "Small", "Medium", "Large" };

string output = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(product);
//{
//  "Name": "Apple",
//  "ExpiryDate": "2008-12-28T00:00:00",
//  "Price": 3.99,
//  "Sizes": [
//    "Small",
//    "Medium",
//    "Large"
//  ]
//}

Product deserializedProduct = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Product>(output);
```